# how to export auto-aligned layers at the same canvas size while still preserving their auto-alignment

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm trying to create an animation from daily photos of the same person, with fixed alignment on their face (always in the same position).

I create a layer for each photo, apply auto-align, and the results are perfect.

But when I export each layer, the resulting image loses this auto-alignment.  Each image has a different canvas size (which means the non-photoshop software I'm using to convert n images into an animation, no longer has fixed alignment on the face).

I tried changing the canvas size of each layer image prior to export, making every image's canvas size the same.  But doing so effectively undoes the work of the auto-alignment.

Is there a way to export the auto-aligned layer images while preserving their distribution?  Or just go straight from auto-aligned layers to animated sequence?

Thank you (very new to all this)

Comment: Have you tried cropping the document after aligning, ensuring that you use the "delete cropped pixels" option in the tool options along the top?

Comment: Billy, that worked.  You are my hero, thank you!!